# Retrieving Google App Engine Java SDK from Maven causes OutOfMemoryError in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

I follow the Google Cloud Endpoints tutorial:
http://bradabrams.com/2013/06/google-io-2013-demo-android-studio-cloud-endpoints-synchronized-stopwatch-demo/

Using Android Studio:
1. I created an empty Android Project
2. Generated Google App Engine Backend (Tools -> Google Cloud Tools) 
3. Tried to deploy Google App Engine locally or remotely (Maven Projects -> Plugins -> appengine -> appengine:devserver or appengine:update

In both cases I get:

```
[INFO] Google App Engine Java SDK - Running Development Server
[INFO] 
[INFO] Retrieving Google App Engine Java SDK from Maven
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.8.0/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.0.zip
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.8.0/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.0.zip (122021 KB at 4079.2 KB/sec)
[ERROR] Java heap space -> [Help 1]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:211)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:252)
    at com.google.appengine.SdkResolver.getSdk(SdkResolver.java:153)
    at com.google.appengine.SdkResolver.getSdk(SdkResolver.java:64)
    at com.google.appengine.devappserver.AbstractDevAppServerMojo.getDevAppServerCommand(AbstractDevAppServerMojo.java:122)
at com.google.appengine.devappserver.DevAppServerRunner.execute(DevAppServerRunner.java:40)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/OutOfMemoryError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the heap size of the Maven runner here:

[image: heap size]